# How to inspect total amount of celery worker？

Tags: python, subprocess, celery

I start 10 `celery` workers by the following.

```
celery -A worker.celery worker -l info -c 10
```

I need to know the total amount of active `celery` workers.  If the total amout of active workers are not bigger than 10, we can handle the new task. If not, the new task has to wait till a worker finished. Here is the code to check the total amount of active workers.

```
 import json
 import subprocess


def get_celery_worker():
    bash_command = "celery -A worker inspect active -j"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    output_string = output.decode("utf-8")
    output_json = json.loads(output_string)
    number_of_celery_worker = 0
    if len(list(output_json.values())[0]) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        for value in list(output_json.values())[0]:
            for v in value.values():
                if v == 'run_task':  # Here run_task is the worker name.
                    number_of_celery_worker += 1 
    return int(number_of_celery_worker / 2)  # Every task contains two run_task
```

I start 10 tasks on by one every second.The subprocess gives me the total workers are: `0`, `0`, `1`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `6`.

Anyone has an idea to implement this or any other idea to count workers?

Comment: can I get a code that actually does something seperately to understand more about the environment in which the code will run?

Comment: @Alphonsus see my updates.

Comment: I need the code that will preceed you calling the function to understand the preconditions, I have an idea, on another way to do this that is easier, but I am not sure of the state of the program before your function can be called. As you know, this program on its own is not executable without errors.

Comment: @Alphonsus You may try to put your answer first.

Comment: Strange logic... `apply_async` is needed for adding task to queue. Let's say that you have 2 workers (yes, it is possible to set maximum number of workers in celery config). After that you are adding 10 tasks in queue (without checking workers count) and two workers process it one by one. That is meaning of `async`. If you are waiting while previous worker completes its job, it is not `async`. You don't need celery at all in this case. Just start simple python process and check count with ps command: `ps aux | grep python_script.py`

Comment: @rzlvmp You right. It seems I have wrote something that causes misunderstanding. Updated.

Comment: Still don't understand. Celery is a daemon process that is managing number of workers by itself. If worker is failed (ended with exception), celery is trying to start new one. Every worker is continuously listening for a queue and pick a task if it exists. Celery should manage workers by itself. You don't need celery if you plan to manage workers (==single processes) manually

Comment: @rzlvmp Here I need to figire out how many workers are active. If the total amout of active workers are beyond my limitation. Let's say, I start 10 workers by `celery -A worker.celery worker -l info -c 10`, if there are 10 workers are active and a new task is given by the consumer. I will tell the consumer he has to wait.

Comment: @rzlvmp see the updates.

Comment: `I will tell the consumer he has to wait` → Isn't better idea is to check how many tasks waiting in queue to determine waiting time? If you have 1000 tasks waiting for process in queue it is no matter how many workers are active. Waiting time will be definitely long. In other way you may use celery [signals](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html). Count `+1` on `task_prerun` and `-1` on `task_failure/task_success/task_rejected`. And store this count value somewhere in file or database

Comment: @rzlvmp I have to give the queue number if a task is waiting.

Answer (score 1):

In Celery parlance "celery worker" is actually the main process that controls everything, including communication and management of the underlying "worker- processes".

So, when you run a command like `celery -A worker.celery worker -l info -c 10`, you will actually start a SINGLE process that Celery referes to as "celery worker". Since you did not specify the concurrency type, Celery worker will assume the *prefork* concurrency, which is based on processes.

The `-c 10` parameter (concurrency level) instructs the Celery worker that you want 10 worker-processes. So, when Celery worker starts, it will create 10 worker processes and will communicate with them when when some task needs to be executed.

Sure there is much more going on underneath... For an example, Celery worker may every now and then kill some and replace them with new, fresh worker processes, etc.

As for the management and monitoring API, Celery provides the `stats` inspect command, https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#worker-statistics, giving you statistics for each node (Celery worker). Run something like `celery -A worker.celery inspect stats` to see what I mean. Statistics are available through the API as well (if you want to do some Python scripting) - once you get the result look for "pool" key. It should contain something like:

```
       "pool": {
            "max-concurrency": 60,
            "max-tasks-per-child": "N/A",
            "processes": [
                4262,
                4263,
                ... skipped ...
            ],
            "put-guarded-by-semaphore": false,
            "timeouts": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "writes": {
                "all": "0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02",
                "avg": "0.02",
                "inqueues": {
                    "active": 0,
                    "total": 60
                },
                "raw": "92, 99, 86, 118, 104, 62, 119, 115, 74, 102, 106, 95, 76, 88, 59, 114, 96, 86, 140, 84, 75, 75, 71, 79, 43, 76, 97, 51, 71, 44, 132, 106, 91, 71, 72, 148, 54, 117, 144, 83, 101, 105, 51, 74, 114, 69, 84, 92, 72, 86, 125, 67, 80, 97, 64, 88, 101, 61, 90, 94",
                "strategy": "fair",
                "total": 5330
            }
        },
```

The "processes" list contains process IDs of all worker-processes spawned by Celery worker. That number is the number you are looking for. It will however be a constant - 10, as that is what you asked from the Celery worker (the `-c 10` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, First things first**

I do not understand the concept of celery, and have not written a code using it till now, but I did some reading to help answer this question and I understood that one can use the package as a command and also as a python API, but I am still trying to get if it is possible to use both in a program or if these are two methods that should or cannot be used together and that is why I would like to see your code.

**Given that your full code is unavailable and that the one given raises errors**

I assume you can also mix your command line usage with python API usage. There is a class `State` in the module `celery.events.state` which is fundamental here. If you can find a way to get an object of `State` from the current variables and procedures in your environment which I have no idea about, then getting the number of workers is straightforward from the method `alive_workers()`
Should you be new to the API, the following resources might prove helpful:

1. [Celery Doc Homepage](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/#)
2. [Celery User guide](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/index.html)
3. [Celery API reference](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/index.html)
4. [celery.events.state documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.events.state.html)

Hope this helps, but if it doesn't leave your question in the comment section below, I will reply as soon as I can. Thank you.